# Maximum area enclosed by water droplets

Tags: algorithm

I recently came across the following question online while preparing for an interview

> Imagine a random distribution of water droplets spread across the whiteboard, design an algorithm to create the maximal enclosed area by connecting the water droplets with lines.

The question was vague and didn't have more information. I came up with a partial approach but I am not too sure if it is correct.

Assuming water droplets represent points on a graph, in order to find the largest area enclosed by connecting the water droplets we would need to:

1. Find all the points that lie on the periphery of this cluster. Connecting all the points that lie on the periphery or the boundary will give the largest area.
2. To find the points that lie on the periphery:

   1. Sort the x and y coordinates. Connect the points that lie on the extremes. So we would connect the point that has the maximum x coordinate with the minimum x coordinate and also to the max/min y coordinates. (I am not too sure of this approach.)
3. I wasn't sure how to find the area of this figure since it could range from 3 to n sides.

I could also validate and make sure that the number of the water droplets in the input is greater than or equal to 3 since we need at least 3 points to find the area.

Edit: 
The above algorithm to find the points on the periphery of the water droplet distribution is incorrect.

Comment: And what are you asking?

Comment: @rvheddeg 2 things. Whether the algorithm I specified for finding the largest object is correct (To find the points that lie on the periphery:). And what approach should be used to find the area of an n sided polygon.

Answer (score 2):

As you already noted, the question is vague. Specifically, it is unclear how the "maximal enclosed area" is defined.

It seems that the questioner is interested in finding the convex hull. There is a [variety of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to connect all the droplets, you are on the right track by looking for points on the periphery  to use as vertices of a convex polygon. Once you find a convex polygon that encloses all the droplets and has its vertices on droplets, you can find the area by integrating under the "top" of your polygon using the trapezoid rule, the area under the "bottom" of your polygon using the trapezoid rule, and then subtract. The "top" and "bottom" of your polygon will be sequences of droplets; they will meet at the leftmost and rightmost droplet on your polygon. You can figure out the rest of the sequence by taking the next "top" droplet to be the one of two choices which is higher up. Suppose the points on your polygon are as below:

```
6 |     c
5 |           e    
4 | a    
3 |   b
2 |         d
1 |
0 L_____________
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The leftmost and rightmost points are `a` and `e`, respectively. Starting from `a`, to determine the next "top" point, we compare `c` and `b` and find `c` is higher, so we know `c` is part of "top" and `b` is part of "bottom". Then we simply follow the lines and find "top" is "a-c-e" and "bottom" is "a-b-d-e".

The area under "top" can be found using the trapezoid rule to integrate under each line segment:

```
(1,4) to (3,6)
A = w x (h1 + h2) / 2
A = (3 - 1) x (4 + 6) / 2 = 2 x 5 = 10

(3,6) to (6,5)
A = w x (h1 + h2) / 2
A = (6 - 3) x (6 + 5) / 2 = 3 x 5.5 = 16.5

A = 10 + 16.5 = 26.5
```

Integrating under the bottom works the same way:

```
A = 3.5 + 7.5 + 3.5 = 14.5
```

Now we subtract to find the area of the polygon is 12.

**HOWEVER**

If your task is to maximize the enclosed area by forming an enclosed area that connects *all* droplets, the problem becomes very different. Determine whether that's what you need to do or not.